# RestRequest.getRequestForUpsert fails with BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400

Tags: visualforce, android

I am trying to create and android app with salesforce connectivity, while creating a new record i tried the following functions out of which getRequestForCreate works but getRequestforupsert fails with error.

> 01-23 02:27:19.991: E/Volley(18363): [2449]
>   BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for
>   c/CatId_c/30">https://na9.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Cat_c/CatId_c/30

I have also included screenshot of the custom table in salesforce.

```
    public void onUpdateClick(View v)  {
    Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    fields.put("Name", nameField.getText().toString());

    fields.put("Quantity__c", quantityField.getText().toString());
    fields.put("Price__c", priceField.getText().toString());
    fields.put("CatId__c", 30);

    try {
        saveData(fields);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

private void saveData(Map<String, Object> fields) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    RestRequest restRequest;
    try {

        final String objectType = "Cat__c";
        final String externalIdField = "CatId__c";
        final String externalId = "30";

        // getRequestforcreate  works 
        //restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForCreate(getString(R.string.api_version), "Cat__c", fields);

        // getRequestForUpsert fails
        restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForUpsert(getString(R.string.api_version), objectType, externalIdField, externalId, fields);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        MainActivity.showError(this, e);
        return;
    }

    client.sendAsync(restRequest, new AsyncRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse result) {
            try {
                NewDetailActivity.this.finish();
            } 

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                MainActivity.showError(NewDetailActivity.this, e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {

            MainActivity.showError(NewDetailActivity.this, e);

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure upsert doesn't work well with autonumber fields (how could it?) try changing the type of the catId field.

Comment: Thanks @superfell upsert works now, after the required changes in the salesforce, it is getting inserted to the salesforce database

Comment: But now I get these errors.
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 201 for https://na9.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Cat__c/CatId__c/30

NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.entityToBytes(BasicNetwork.java:202)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:104)

at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
Do you have any pointers

Answer (score 1):

For 201 problem, check this workaround, at least it works for me.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/449

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange. Would you mind actually posing some of the code and explain how this solves the problem ? We aim to build knowledge within this site rather than reference it elsewhere.